# How to match two values from an NSObject array? (Obj c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsobject, nslog

I wasn't sure how to phrase the question but I'm hoping you'll be able to help.

I have a Book object. Each book has a title, an ID string, and a boolean for whether or not it has been read.  I can get the values of each title, ID string, and boolean separately - but I can't seem to get which book belongs to which boolean. All the data is contained in the BookDataController file as arrays. The boolean value is saved in nsuserdefaults.

```
@interface Book : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *readIDString;
@property BOOL hasRead;
@end
```

Here is the code I'm using to get the values of the arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *dataSource;
dataSource = _bookDataController.bookInfoArray;

NSArray *bookTitles = [dataSource valueForKey:@"title"];
NSLog(@"DataSource Title: %@", bookTitles);
```

(Returns: ["title1", "title2", "title3, etc])

```
NSArray *titlesRead = [dataSource valueForKey:@"hasRead"];
NSLog(@"DataSource Bool: %@", titlesRead);
```

(Returns: [false, false, true, etc])

```
NSArray *readIDs = [dataSource valueForKey:@"readIDString"];
NSLog(@"DataSource ReadID: %@", readIDs);
```

(Returns: ["id1", "id2", "id3", etc])

I know that I can get the values of all keys saved to NSUserDefaults like so:

```
NSArray *keys = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];
for(NSString *key in keys)
{
    NSLog(@"value: %@ forKey: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key], key);
}
```

But this returns all kinds of defaults that are being used throughout the app and not in any sortable order that I can tell.

So my question is this: How can I log out the values of each book so that I get the titles that go with the correct booleans? Is this possible?

(Example: "book title": false, "book title": true, etc)

Now that I am typing this out, it looks like a dictionary! Yet I don't know how to get to this point. It has been days on Stack Overflow to get the current calls with NSArray as it is!  That should indicate my level of understanding at this point. :)

Better yet, now that I'm thinking about this some more, I'd like to return this instead:

("id1": false, "id2": false, "id3": true, etc)

(Both calls would be magnificent!)

Please tell me if I need to clarify anything or if you need more code.  Thanks so much, everyone!

Comment: You need to persist your `Book` objects rather than just separate arrays.  You can use `NSKeyedArchiver`, but honestly you should use Core Data rather than treating `NSUserDefaults` as a data store

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've started a couple tutorials on Core Data but it's still a little above my head.  I will persist, however!  At this point only the booleans are saved to nsuserdefaults and all the other info is called from the data file. I just wanted to be able to log it out in the console.  It all works great in my tableview.  It's a different process in how the code is added to the tableview and how I need to call it to see it in the console. That's what I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Comment: You want to return id, title, and boolean where book is read OR boolean is true. @IWannaLearn Right? If it is then i will post my code

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16710509/4225505. It did  exactly what I asked for. Woohoo, getting close! I wanted to log all the values of each key so that all the values "matched up". Sometimes it's hard to articulate the question when you're just beginning but here is my code based on that answer:

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int idx = 0; idx<[bookTitles count]; idx++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"title": bookTitles[idx], @"readIDString": readIDs[idx], @"hasRead": titlesRead[idx]};
    [anArray addObject:dict];
}

NSLog(@"%@", anArray);

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"hasRead" ascending:NO];


[anArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];

NSLog(@"%@", anArray);
```

This returns: 
[{"title": "Title1", "readIDString": "id1", "hasRead": true}, 
{"title": "Title2", "readIDString": "id2", "hasRead": false}, etc]

Sorting by "hasRead" lists all the true values first.